# Is there a class like a Dictionary without a Value template? Is HashSet<T> the correct answer?

Tags: c#

I have 3 tables: Foos, Bars and FooBarConfirmations

I want to have a in-memory list of FooBarConfirmations by their hash:

```
FooID   BarID   Hash
1       1       1_1
2       1       2_1
1       2       1_2
2       2       2_2
```

What would be the best Class to use to store this type of structure in-memory, so that I can quickly check to see if a combination exists like so:

```
list.Contains("1_2");
```

I can do this with Dictionary<string,anything>, but it "feels" wrong.

HashSet looks like the right tool for the job, but does it use some form of hashing algorithm in the background to do the lookups efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is based around the same technique as the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class, so yes, it will be just as fast.